# Jit оптимизация , в профилировании

Tags: java

Читаю я статью о *JMH* и тут встречаю такой абзац :

> By default JHM forks a new java process for each trial (set of iterations). This is required to defend the test from previously collected “profiles” – information about other loaded classes and their execution information. **For example, if you have 2 classes implementing the same interface and test the performance of both of them, then the first implementation (in order of testing) is likely to be faster than the second one (in the same JVM), because JIT replaces direct method calls to the first implementation with interface method calls after discovering the second implementation**

Что означает фраза "*JIT replaces direct method calls to the first implementation with interface method calls*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это значит, что в процессе прогона теста для первой реализации интерфейса, JIT в процессе прогрева соптимизирует код таким образом, что все вызовы будут происходить не через интерфейс, а на прямую к самой имплементации, минуя интерфейс. После этого, когда начнется прогон теста для второй имплементации, JIT заметит, что теперь имплементация изменилась и нужно снова выполнять виртуальные вызовы, что медленнее.

JMH, естественно, ничего не знает про оптимизации JIT'а, и не может подсказать ему, что теперь все вызовы нужно выполнять непосредственно над второй имплементацией. Соответственно, пока JIT собирает новый профиль, приличная часть виртуальных вызовов ко второй имплементации повлияет на статистику JMH в худшую сторону.

Чтобы этого избежать, JMH создает новый процесс, в котором JIT еще не имеет никакой статистики, выполняет прогревочные итерации, чтобы JIT собрал новый профиль, и начинает собирать новую статистику.

Таким образом, оба теста для обеих имплементаций выполняются в приблизительно одинаковых условиях, что дает возможность более точно оцень разницу между имплементациями.

Comment: Надо глянуть байт код, что бы убедиться, что сначала вызов метода происходит в интерфейсе

Comment: @voipp В байткоде вы увидите invoke_dynamic. JIT компилирует байткод в машинный код. Поэтому смотреть вам нужно не в байткод, а в ключать лог компиляций и смотреть на ассемблер.

Comment: @a_gura а не invokeinterface?

Comment: @zzashpaupat да, invokeinterface.

Comment: а почему JMH просто не делает дополнительный прогрев перед выполнением замера 2й имплементации)

Comment: @voipp С чистого листа условия более равные.